# How can I append the value of an input text into a variable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I tried using:

```
$("#userInput").appendTo("gList") //The name of my variable is gList
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Please look in the documentation. You want `var gList=$("#userInput").val();`

Comment: If gList is an array: `gList.push( $("#userInput").val() );`

Answer (score 1):

As i understand this `gList` this is an array so you have to do next

```
var gList = []; 
// ... do some job
var inputValue = $("#userInput").val();  //console.log(inputValue)
gList.push(inputValue); // console.log(gList)
```

If `gList` is a string you can concatenate it `gList = gList + inputValue`

Thanks